# Swift SceneKit and loading 3D models

Tags: swift, scenekit

I wrote these lines of code but when I start I will report the following error:

> 2017-10-02 19: 53: 38.856088 + 0200 SceneViewApp [38539: 1262873]
>   fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

yet the file is in the folder shown.

I saved the 3d model as .dae and after converted to .scn

How can I fix the problem? thank you

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let scene = SCNScene(named: "3Dmodels/coffee.scn")!
        _ = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "coffee.scn", recursively: true)!
    }
}
```

Comment: There are two lines that force unwrap an optional in your question. On which of those lines are you seeing this error?

Comment: only the last line shows the error

Answer (score 0):

Since the error is happening on this line:

```
_ = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "coffee.scn", recursively: true)!
```

It looks like there is not child node with the name "coffee.scn", which means that `childNode(withName:recursively:)` returns `nil`, which then is force unwrapped (`!`) triggering the fatal error.

---

Without the assets you are working on, I can't really tell you what the name of the node should be.

I don't see a reason why a node name would include a file extension (".scn") so it might be that the node is just called "coffee". You can open the asset file in Xcode and select the node you are looking for and see its name in the Node Inspector. You could also enumerate all the child nodes (using `enumerateChildNodes(_:)`) and print their names to see a list of all possible node names.